# Where to send the AWS Organization invite from?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-organizations

We have an existing GovCloud account, let's call it team #1 account. We would like to invite another GovCloud account (for team # 2) to join our AWS Organization. I have already set up the organization under both team #1  GovCloud account and the commercial account. We would like to just be the payer for that team #2 account.

So my question is do I send the team #2 the invite from the Commercial account or from our team #1 account? If we can do both, what are the differences between the two approach?

I just need to know if we should send the invite from the commercial account or from our govcloud account? Thank you